# How to get access to current context from XS?

Tags: perl, perl-xs, perlapi

When a user calls `XS` from `main::` package we can not use

```
caller_cx(0, NULL);
```

because there is no frames for `main::` and for `XSUB` [DOC](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#caller_cx)

> Note that XSUBs don't get a stack frame, so C will return information for the immediately-surrounding Perl code

How to get the `file:line` info the `XSUB` is called from, hints for `main::` scope etc. info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from [`mess_sv`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/v5.26.1:/util.c#l1424) (called by Perl API functions `warn` and `croak`, which append line information like the Perl functions `warn` and `die`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Inline C => <<'__EOS__';

void testing() {
    dXSARGS;

    /*
     * Try and find the file and line for PL_op.  This will usually be
     * PL_curcop, but it might be a cop that has been optimised away.  We
     * can try to find such a cop by searching through the optree star ting
     * from the sibling of PL_curcop.
     */
    if (PL_curcop) {
        const COP *cop =
            Perl_closest_cop(aTHX_ PL_curcop, OpSIBLING(PL_curcop), PL_op, FALSE);
        if (!cop)
            cop = PL_curcop;

        if (CopLINE(cop)) {
            EXTEND(SP, 2);
            mPUSHs(newSVpv(OutCopFILE(cop), 0));
            mPUSHs(newSViv((IV)CopLINE(cop)));
            XSRETURN(2);
        }
    }

    XSRETURN(0);
}

__EOS__

say join ":", testing();
```

A little bit about `PL_curcop` [here](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/v5.26.1:/cop.h#l9).

Comment: It seems every current thing is available as `PL_cur*`